# TV series of a spy

Tags: story-identification, tv

I am looking for a old TV series, which I used to watch in my childhood (1995-2000). Actually, I am from India and that serial was dubbed in India's national language. I would like to watch that Scifi series again. Below what I remember about the TV series:

There was a SPY who do the task assigned to him. He used to have camera in his contact lenses which helped his team mate (Who sits at the headquarter and instruct the spy looking on the computer screen) to see excatly what that SPY is watching. I remember the name of the SPY and that was Curtain Dial (Please excuse me if I missed the spelling of the name as English is not my primary language). Could you please assist me giving me the name of that serial?

Any guesses ?

**Edit 1**

Here I have some more information about the serial, that it was a live-action and it was for adult because the actor was a spy, so some graphics content of violence was there.

Comment: Some things that *might* help; Was it live-action (that is, with actors) or animated in some way? What would you think was its targeted at children or rather at adults?

Comment: @bitmask That is, indeed, something I should specify while writing the question it was a *live-action* and was for *adult* because as the actor was a spy so some graphics content of *violence* was there

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite You can edit that information into your question, just click the 'edit' link below the question body to make your changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A fast search on the internet with the right key words brought up **Fortune Hunter** where the main character is named Carlton Dial.

[Source](http://www.crazyabouttv.com/fortunehunter.html) - [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108776/)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dm5A38H-mXw

Answer (score 1):

The show had different spies in different episodes. I think Doug McLure was one. Sometimes the backroom scientist was played by Burgess Meredith. I think the show was called "Search Control."

Comment: We already have an accepted answer, but other answers that match the question are still welcome because they might help later querents. But, for that, we need some context. How does your work match the question? Are there enhanced contact lenses?

Comment: My question description may match other stories but **Fortune Hunter** was the series which I was looking for. But thanks anyways for your answer. I would love to watch similar series.